# Running Python Script From PHP that create thread and then kill it in window 8

Tags: php, python

I have a PHP script that runs a python script with exec("C:/Python26/python C:/xampp/htdocs/timeout.py");. It works nicely, but I don't want to wait that python script to finish. Also I need to run remaining php code (echo "Time Out") only without waiting python reply.Thanks in advance.

```
enter code here
<form action="spg.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div align="center"><input type="submit"name="submit" value="INSERT"> &n
    <input type="submit" name="show" value="Show">
</div>
</form>

enter code here
<?php
    $start_time = time();
    $timeVar=true;
    while(true) {
    if ((time() - $start_time) < 300) {
    $read= exec("start C:/Python26/python C:/xampp/htdocs/testing/timeout.py");
  // timeout, function took longer than 300 seconds
}
else
{
  echo "Time out";
  /*sys.exit();*/
}
```

}

?>

```
enter code here
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def do_actions():
"""
Function that should timeout after 5 seconds. It simply prints a number and waits 1 second.
:return:
"""
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    # print(i)
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
# We create a Process
action_process = Process(target=do_actions)

# We start the process and we block for 5 seconds.
action_process.start()
action_process.join(timeout=600)

# We terminate the process.
action_process.terminate()
print("Hey there! I timed out! You can do things after me!")
```

Comment: This python script is just a fire and forget as in you don't need to parse out a result from it?

Comment: and some code would also help to understand

Comment: Python code return value in 10 minutes.But I want to display on browser as (echo "Time out";) in 5 minutes without waiting return value.Thanks in advance.

Comment: firstpg.php
<form action="spg.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div align="center"><input type="submit"name="submit" value="INSERT"> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <input type="submit" name="show" value="Show">
  </div>
</form>

Comment: secondpg.php
<?php
$start_time = time();
  $timeVar=true;
  while(true) {
    if ((time() - $start_time) < 300) {
      $read= exec("start C:/Python26/python C:/xampp/htdocs/testing/timeout.py");
      // timeout, function took longer than 300 seconds
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Time out";
      /*sys.exit();*/
    }
}     
  
?>